# diagonalisability of matrix few properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

What are the most important things one should remember to check the diagonalisability of a matrix?

Please help, I have exams on next week.
Say some best and easy methods,time efficient.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Characterisation) has some nice ways to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\Bbb C)$.

Some common criteria are:

1. If $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then $A$ is diagonalizable.
2. $A$ is diagonalizable if, and only if, the sum of the geometric multiplicties of all the eigenvalues equals $n$. (Note that 1. is a particular case of this).
3. $A$ is normal if, and only if, $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable.
4. $A$ is hermitic if, and only if, $A$ unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix with only real entries.
5. $A$ is unitary if, and only if, $A$ is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix which entries on the main diagonal have absolute value equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial has distinct roots and factors into linear factor.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [diagonalisability of matrix few properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix)
in Wikipedia, by coincidence this article has the same title as your question.