# Linearly dependent eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read a theorem that says squared matrix $A_{n\times n}$ is diagonalizable iff there is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors ,each of which is an eigen-vector of $A_{n\times n}$ .

I understand from the theorem that if $A_{n\times n}$ has at least two dependent eigen-vectors
then $A_{n\times n}$ is not diagonalizable. Is it true?and according to this I want to understand when a matrix has linearly dependent eigenvectors ? (eigenvectors is a set of vectors)
In other words if there is'nt any set of linearly independent set of eigenvectors for a matrix, then does that mean that the matrix is not diagonalizable?

Comment: Can't even begin to understand your question.

Comment: can you explain where is not obvious?

Comment: What is the definition of a dependent eigenvector?

Comment: I mean linearly dependent

Comment: Well, sets are linearly dependent/independent, not eigenvectors. And obviously any set $\{v\}$ where $v$ is not zero is linearly independent.

Comment: @EKH You just got a downvote from me, and the downvote will remain until your question remains as it is. Please, state a clear unambiguous and coherent question. A linearly dependent vector is a mathematically nonsensical statement. A vector is not dependent, only a set of vectors can be linearly dependent or independent.

Comment: I mean linearly dependent eigenvectors,eigenvectors is a set

Comment: @EKH Then edit your question. Use coherent sentences and the closest approximation to a mathematical language that you are capable of.

Comment: You are probably asking something else: You want to know, when an eigenspace of a matrix has dimension bigger than one… Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @5xum I rewrite the question as you ordered

Comment: @EKH The question now look OK, so I removed my downvote and close vote. In future, try to post question that are worded at least as good as this one is at the moment. It makes it easier for the community to help you. I have also posted my answer now that I know what you are asking.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372347/diagonalisability-of-matrix-few-properties/372359#372359).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The theorem states, correctly, that *IF* the matrix $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

That does *NOT* mean that if $A$ has two dependent eigenvectors, that it is not diagonalizable. In fact, if $A$ has at least one eigenvector $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$, then $2x$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ since $A(2x)=2Ax=2\lambda x=\lambda (2x)$. And since $\{x,2x\}$ is not a linearly independent set, this means that $A$ has two linearly dependent vectors. Does that mean $A$ is not diagonalizable? Of course not!

You actually made two logical mistakes.

You know that if statement $p$ ($A$ has $n$ linearly dependent eigenvectors) is true, then statement $q$ ($A$ is diagonalizable) is true, so in other words $p\implies q$. Then you found another statement, $c$ ($A$ has two linearly independent eigenvectors).

Then, you made two mistakes:

1. You claim that if $c$ is true, then $p$ is not true (in fact, any matrix with at least one eigenvector has two dependent eigenvectors, but it can still have $n$ linearly dependent eigenvectors. In fact, whenever $p$ is true, $c$ is also true!
2. You then wanted to conclude that since $p$ is not true, then $q$ is not true. This is a very common mistake, but if $p\implies q$, then $\neg p$ does *not* imply $\neg q$! For example, the statement "Rex is a dog" being true means that the statement "Rex has fur" is true, however, the statement "Rex is not a dog" does not mean that "Rex has no fur" is true!

Comment: I think what he is asking is that if you are not able to find a set of linearly independent set of eigenvectors for a matrix, then does that mean that your matrix is not diagonalizable?

Comment: @ParthThakkar OP says "I understand from the theorem that if $A_{n\times n}$ has at least two dependent eigen-vectors then $A_{n\times n}$ is not diagonalizable" and this statement is not true and is adressed in my answer. If OP meant something else, I think he can explain that himself

Comment: Yeah sure, but I was just trying to help. One more reason for giving in my own interpretation was that I myself do not have an answer for that - that is, what I believe he is asking.

Comment: @ParthThakkar For that, I think the Jordan form should be helpful...

Comment: @ParthThakkar Sure you know the answer. Just argue by contraposition."If a matrix is diagonalizable, then you can find 'sufficient' linearly independent eigenvectors".

Comment: Yes! Indeed! Thank you.

Comment: @ParthThakkar is right he said exactly what I wanted to say . if you are not able to find a set of linearly independent set of eigenvectors for a matrix, then does that mean that your matrix is not diagonalizable?

Comment: @5xum again I rewrite the question take a look especially last part

Comment: @EKH The last statement in your question is correct.

Comment: @5xum my question was that under which conditions the last part happens?

Comment: @EKH Always. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. This means that if no set of $n$ eigenvectors is linearly independent, then $A$ cannot be diagonalizable.

Comment: @5xum I mean under which conditions set of n eigenvectors is not linearly independent?

Comment: @EKH when there exists a linear combination of those vectors that is equal to $0$.