# Suppose $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix with distinct eigenvalues...

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$, what is the minimal polynomial of $A$?

Can someone please give me a concise way of describing the minimal polynomial when we have $k$ distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: Do you know anything about the size of $S$? Does it have, say, $k$ rows?

Comment: Use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/372355) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** for every eigenvalue, $m_A(\lambda_k) = 0$.  So, $(x - \lambda_k)$ divides $m_A(x)$. Note that $m_A$ has degree at most $k$.